# How to add uisearch bar to a tableview using interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, interface-builder

How do we add `uisearch bar` to a `table view` using `interface builder`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement the UISearchBar on a UITableView in iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295450/how-do-i-implement-the-uisearchbar-on-a-uitableview-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't do that using interface builder.

You need to implement the DataSource and Delegater of the UITableView to initialize and add contents to the table and while you are doing that you can add the UISearchBar in a particular cell.

But that is a bad design as such the user wont be able to use search option as he scrolls down.

so instead take my advice add UISearchBar on top of UITableView using IB. Its easy to do and the user will be happy too.