# How can I create a Spotlight-like search bar in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

How can I create a Spotlight-like search bar in an iPhone application?

Comment: You really have to give more descriptive titles, anyone in the world can tell your question is about iPhone programming.

Comment: You've asked quite a few questions (with extremely non-descriptive titles) looking for "sample code". Are you aware that Apple offers sample code you can learn from? See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Comment: This is also the third time you've asked pretty much the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779125/iphone-programming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743523/iphone-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag a UISearchBar into IB and connect it to your view controller. It needs a delegate to function so, you could make your view controller conform to the UISearchBarDelegate protocol or you could do the searching in your data layer. But the best way is to use a UISearchDisplayController. Any way the delegate needs access to the data being searched so that it can use a predicate to filter the data. [Here's](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/samplecode/TableSearch/TableSearch.zip) one of Apple's examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just drag and drop a UISearchBar in Interface Builder and link it up as normal... Then you need some code to search your tableview/data. There are numerous ways to do that, documented all over the internet. Google is your friend.

Comment: will u please send me any of the links to search the samplecode i tried but i din't get it.correctly