# IOS : Implement a search text field like spotlight search

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I was trying to implement a spotlight-like search bar in my app. The spotlight search bar has no opaque/translucent bar behind it. But if I add a UISearchBar to my view or use Three20's SearchViewConroller, there is an opaque/translucent bar behing the search text field. One way to get rid of the bar is to have just a text field. But then I am left with the tedious job of hooking up all the search-related actions like registering when the search button is pressed etc.

So my question : 
Is there a library which I can include which allows me to add a search bar to a tableview, without having any background opaque/translucent bar?
OR
Is there a library which gives me a way of adding a text field to a tableview's TableHeaderView. This text field should have rounded corners and I should be able to register user actions like clicking of 'cancel search' button or 'search' button.

If someone has done the hard work of hooking all this up, code samples are welcome too :).

PS : I know this looks similar to [How can I create a Spotlight-like search bar in an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782298/how-can-i-create-a-spotlight-like-search-bar-in-an-iphone-app) and [iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743523/iphone-programming) but it is not :)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a background image to the UISarchBar? (the background image would be a transparent empty image).